# Trying to disable div section of form only if the values of 2 fields are 1 and checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to disable a section of a form if it has been signed by a supervisor using 2 fields.
The problem is it works too good. It disables the section on a new form.  For brevity  here are the 2 fields, the hidden values of those fields and the jquery script.

This is the code of the fields when adding a new form or record.
These 2 forms are within the div with the id supersection.
Here is the html for the 2 fields
First the hidden values of the fields in the form then the html of the fields themselves.

```
<div id="supersection" style="border: none;">

<input type="hidden" name="supersignoff" value="0"/>
<input type="hidden" name="superdeclare" value="0"/>

<label class="padd2left" for="supersignoff">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="supersignoff" name="supersignoff" />    
Complete and sign</label>

<label for="superdeclare">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="superdeclare" name="superdeclare"  />
I have completed with the best info from all parties</label>
```

Below is the jquery script.  This disables the whole section.

```
$(function(){
   var signoff = $("#supersignoff").val();
   var sdeclare = $("#superdeclare").val()
   if(signoff=="1" && sdeclare=="1"){
      $("#supersection *").prop("disabled",true);
  }
})
```

Again the section is being disabled even when it is a new form.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
   var signoff = $("#supersignoff").prop('checked');
   var sdeclare = $("#superdeclare").prop('checked')
   if(signoff && sdeclare){
      $("#supersection *").prop("disabled",true);
  }
});
```

.prop('checked') will give you the status of checkbox is checked or not, but not `.val()`.

Ref: [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)